# Is it possible to use Torii with FastBoot in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, torii

I'm using Torii 0.10.1 with Ember 3.5 in order to use facebook-connect by injecting the torii service into the controller.

This works fine, but as soon as I enable FastBoot, I'm getting the following error:

```
There was an error running your app in fastboot. More info about the error: 
 ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at loadScript (/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-output_path-foo.tmp/assets/addon-tree-output/torii/providers/-private/utils.js:24:1)
    at Ember.RSVP.Promise.then.window.fbAsyncInit (/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-output_path-foo.tmp/assets/addon-tree-output/torii/providers/facebook-connect.js:34:1)
    at initializePromise (/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-output_path-foo.tmp/assets/rsvp.js:397:1)
    at new Promise (/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-output_path-foo.tmp/assets/rsvp.js:877:1)
    at fbLoad (/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-output_path-foo.tmp/assets/addon-tree-output/torii/providers/facebook-connect.js:26:1)
    at Class.init (/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-output_path-foo.tmp/assets/addon-tree-output/torii/providers/facebook-connect.j
```